# Java program for reading data from file and display in predefined format

Tags: java, file-handling

I have a text file which is in the following format:

```
one,
two,
tree,
four,
five,
six,
......and so on
```

Now I need a Java program which produce output in the following format:

```
number is one and number is two
number is two and number is three
number is three and number is four
number is five and number is six
......and so on
```

I tried it to do in various ways but could not get the correct output.

My code is:

```
public static void readData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File f=new File("test.txt");
    try {
        FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String line1[] = line.split(",");
            System.out.println("Number is : "+line1[0]+" and Number is :"+line1[1]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: code please? need more info

Comment: Read the [help]. Your question is totally unsuitable for StackOverflow. If you have indeed tried in various ways, you should be able to post your code and show us what the problem is.

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Following code can help you -

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("FILE_PATH"));
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(
                "number is " + list.get(i - 1).replace(",", "") + " and number is " + list.get(i).replace(",", ""));
    }
```